# How to change the text color of the overflow menu item to a different color using Sherlock action bar theme

Tags: android, styles, themes, actionbarsherlock

I was trying to figure out, how to change the text color of menu item to a different color using sherlock action bar. The below is the theme i tried out

```
      <style name="MYTHEME" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.ForceOverflow">

         <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/menu_color</item>
         <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/menu_color</item>


        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MYTHEME.ActionBarStyle.DropDownStyle</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MYTHEME.ActionBarStyle.DropDownStyle</item>  

      </style>   

      <style name="MYTHEME.ActionBarStyle.DropDownStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/menu_color</item>
      </style>
```

i was able to change the color of menu item using the above one, but unable to change the color of the overflow menu item through the 'actionDropDownStyle'...

I have also looked at the link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/actionbarsherlock/5lHOKNlXn_4/f9XicMXbFFAJ
but there was only half answer to the question, about changing overflow menu background.

any ideas how to change the text color of overflow menu item?

Answer (score 4):

You have to create your custom spinner style, overriding for example the one provided by ActionBarSherlock library:

```
<style name="SpinnerItemStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>        
</style>
```

Then, reference it in your theme, in spinnerItemStyle item:

```
<item name="spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemStyle</item>
```

**EDIT:**

Note: Make sure your adapter has com.actionbarsherlock.R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item as dropdown item, and com.actionbarsherlock.R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item as spinner item:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> navigationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, com.actionbarsherlock.R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, navigationItems);
navigationAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(com.actionbarsherlock.R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: I have tried the above code but I'm still unable to change the text color of overflow menu items... any ideas? & i don't think that the overflow menu items style is related to TextView.SpinnerItem...

Comment: You have to include that item (spinnerItemStyle) into your Application theme, which has to have as any Sherlock themes as parent.

Comment: In my case MYTHEME is the theme name that i'm using for my application, and as u suggested i have included spinnerItemStyle in my theme, the below link gives the custom theme that i'm using for my application.. [link](http://s9.postimage.org/ojxoymj0f/custom_theme.png)  but nothing worked..let me know if u find any mistake

Answer (score 0):

After lots of searching, one can modify text Color inside <kbd>OverflowMenu</kbd> of `ActionBar` for `ActionBarSherlock`. with following Theme Styles under parent style element only. Still haven't checked all the widget inside `ActionBar` changed or not. Please pardon for that if found out.

`res\values\styles.xml`

```
<style name="Theme.Zname" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_zname</item>
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Overflow.Text.Color</item>
</style>

<style name="Overflow.Text.Color" parent="Widget">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

`res\values-v14\styles.xml`

```
<style name="Theme.Zname" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_zname</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Overflow.Text.Color</item>
</style>

<style name="Overflow.Text.Color" parent="Widget">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```