# ActionBarSherlock Change Text Color of Overflow Action Items

Tags: android, styles, actionbarsherlock, android-spinner

I'm working on an android app and I am using ActionBarSherlock for compatibility. Everything works great so far, except the fact that I want to change the text color of the overflow menu items.

Here's the way they currently look:

[image]

Now, the reason for this is that I am usign Holo.Light.DarkActionBar as the Base theme since that way the icons are white, the text is white on the ActionBar's Title and SubTitle, and some other things.

To my knowledge, and per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615458/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-the-overflow-menu-item-to-a-different-color-usin), I should be able to simply change the following:

```
<!-- For Values -->
<style name="Theme.Laprensa_compat_holo_light_dark_action_bar" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemStyle</item>

<!-- For Values-v14 -->
<style name="Theme.Laprensa_compat_holo_light_dark_action_bar" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemStyle</item>
```

And the `SpinnerItemStyle` is:

```
<style name="SpinnerItemStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Now, that doesn't seem to be working, so I added

```
<item name="spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemStyle</item>
```

To the children theme too:

```
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Laprensa_compat_holo_light_dark_action_bar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
```

It's still a no-go.

The Answer I referenced stated that i should make sure that I am using the correct adapter layout, but in reality, I am not inflating any code myself manually, it's the regular `onCreateOptionsMenu` implementation.

Any ideas on what could I change to make the text black? And you should know that changing `actionMenuTextColor` is for items **hosted on** the action bar itself, and doesn't change the overflow menu items

**EDIT** As per Matthias' answer, I tried the following style:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Styled.Widget.PopupMenu.Large" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

and used it on the main theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Laprensa_compat_holo_light_dark_action_bar" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/TextAppearance.Styled.Widget.PopupMenu.Large</item>
</style>
```

But the text is still non-visible.

Comment: did you find solution for this... i have a same problem

Comment: Nope, I had to roll over to using Sherlock Light as Base theme, and change the color for almost everything else.

Comment: that's what i'm doing right now.... :( can we adress google somehow on this issue

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">
            @style/TextAppearance.Styled.Widget.PopupMenu.Large</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Styled.Widget.PopupMenu.Large"
        parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
</style>
```